# Dispose elements in Swing application

Tags: java, swing

I what to ask what is the best way to dispose UI elements in Swing?

I tried different layouts (`BorderLayout`, `FlowLayout`...) but I could dispose elements quickly and at exactly that point of the screen what I need.  I used method `setLocation(int x,int y)` but it isn't working.

I mean position. I tried setLayout(null) it helped me,but JTable column headers aren't visible. Here is my code(it is compilable)

```
public class Test1 extends JFrame{
public JTable tbGoods=new JTable();
public JScrollPane pane;
DefaultTableModel aModel;
public Test1(){
    setTitle("Make buy");
    setSize(600,600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

     getContentPane().setLayout(null);
     setVisible(true); 
     DisplayAllGoods(null);
}
private void DisplayAllGoods(List<Object> objectList) {
    aModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return true;
    }
    };
    //setting the column name
    Object[] tableColumnNames = new Object[3];
    tableColumnNames[0]="User";
    tableColumnNames[1]="Good";
    tableColumnNames[2]="Price";

    aModel.setColumnIdentifiers(tableColumnNames);
    tbGoods.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    tbGoods.setBounds(93, 293, 388, 143);   
    pane=new JScrollPane(tbGoods);  
    getContentPane().add(tbGoods);
    getContentPane().add(pane);
    this.tbGoods.setModel(aModel);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame gf=new Test1();
gf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
gf.setVisible(true);}}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit. What do you mean by dispose ui elements? In what context? What effect do you want the user to experience? What code have you tried? Best would be to post a small compilable runnable example program, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if possible.

Comment: @andre:  'dispose' means a particular thing in Java, basically 'to get rid of or throw away'.  Did you actually mean 'place' or 'position'?

Answer (score 2):

Well the easiest way would be to just say:

```
mySwingElement = null
```

If you want to remove elements from panels, you can try the method:

```
remove(int index);
```

also you can use:

```
mySwingElement.dispose()
```

It will release all resources related to it

If you want to just make them invisible:

```
 setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have absolute positioning of swing components you may want to use the `null` layout (see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)).

Comment: IMO we should not help people to shoot themselves in the foot.  In that respect `null` layouts are rarely, if ever, the correct or best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I downloaded Jigloo GUI editor and used AbsolutLayout component(to place elements where I want) and into JScrollPane I placed JTable.

```
    public class NewJFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private JTable jTable1;

    /**
    * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                NewJFrame2 inst = new NewJFrame2();
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public NewJFrame2() {
        super();
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            {
                jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
                getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
                jScrollPane1.setBounds(30, 37, 339, 176);
                {
                    TableModel jTable1Model = 
                        new DefaultTableModel(
                                new String[][] { { "One", "Two" }, { "Three", "Four" } },
                                new String[] { "Column 1", "Column 2" });
                    jTable1 = new JTable();
                    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
                    jTable1.setModel(jTable1Model);
                }
            }
            pack();
            setSize(400, 300);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //add your error handling code here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

please read

1/ [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tons of examples http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm

2/ put your JTable to the [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

3/ and at the beginning start to place JComponets by using [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)